# Best way to modify a form control value based on another form control in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-validation

In Angular 2 reactive forms, what is the best way to change a form control's value based on another value?  Is it better to subscribe to my FormGroup's `.valueChanges` method and call `.setValue` on the appropriate form control based on some condition, or to create a custom validator on the FormGroup that call's `.setValue` on the appropriate form control based on some condition?

I like the idea of using a custom validator because then I don't have to worry about another subscribe/unscubscribe, but it doesn't seem like validators are something that should modify the FormGroup other than adding validation errors.

Comment: are you saying that your form control's value is only readable by user other than editable?

Comment: No, I'm think more theoretically.  Like, if a user selects a value in a dropdown and the selected values means that a check box automatically gets selected and disabled. Whats the best way to monitor that the dropdown value was selected and check if the checkbox should therefore be checked and disabled based on the dropdown's selected value?

Comment: `.valueChanges` would be the best way to do it based on your description and also you might need `dirty` to check whether the control has changed or not

Comment: You don't nessecarily have to subscribe to the `FormGroup`'s `.valueChanges()`, you can subscribe to the specific `FormControl`'s `.valueChanges` using `formGroupObj.get('formControlName').valueChanges()`

Comment: I would just tie a change event to the FormControl whose value is being depended upon then `setValue` to the other FormControl.